# SQL GROUP BY with COUNTS - how to always return a row when counts are 0

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, count, group-by

Following on from my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334815/sql-2-counts-in-one-query), I now have the following SQL:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Date, 120) AS Date, 
       COUNT(*)                        AS Total, 
       COUNT(CASE 
               WHEN ErrorCode = -2 THEN 1 
             END)                      AS TimeOutErrors, 
       COUNT(CASE 
               WHEN ErrorCode IS NOT NULL THEN 1 
             END)                      AS TotalErrors 
FROM   Table 
WHERE  Type = 7 
       AND Date = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Dateadd(d, -1, Getdate()), 120) 
GROUP  BY Date
```

which returns all records of type 7 for yesterday with a count of -2 errors and a count of total errors.

However, this returns 0 rows if there are no records of type 7 for yesterday

Is it possible to get it to return all 0s when this is the case?

i.e.:

```
Date       Total TimeOutErrors TotalErrors
---------- ----- ------------- -----------
2010-12-06 0     0             0
```

This query is being parsed by bcp to save to a log file daily using SQL Agent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an `OUTER JOIN`

```
...
FROM   
(SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Dateadd(d, -1, Getdate()), 120) AS [Date]) D
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table T
ON  D.[Date] = T.[Date]  AND T.Type = 7
GROUP BY D.[Date]
```

Comment: That gives me a Total of 1 not 0

Comment: Ah, I changed the `Count(*)` to `Count(T.ErrorCode)` and now get the 0!

Comment: @Shevek - Ah yes, forgot you would need to do that!

Comment: Actually, that then returned 0 for dates when there ARE records as `ErrorCode` is NULL when not present - changed again to `Count(T.ID)` and now it works as expected!

Comment: Yep. You need to choose a non nullable column from T. `pk` would likely be a good choice.